# MySQL + Dapper QueryMultiple: how to execute multiple SELECT queries at once?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, dapper

I'm having a hard time finding this on the internet...

I need to run a `QueryMultiple` command in **Dapper + MySQL**, with a query that would look like this in SQL Server:

```sql
DECLARE @clientDomain VARCHAR(64) SET @clientDomain = 'some-domain';
DECLARE @sessionId VARCHAR(64) SET @sessionId = 'd09a8sd09a7g8gh';

SELECT *
FROM sessions.Sessions Sessions
WHERE Sessions.ClientDomain = @clientDomain AND Sessions.SessionId = @sessionId;

SELECT *
FROM sessions.PageVisits PageVisits
WHERE PageVisits.SessionClientDomain = @clientDomain AND PageVisits.SessionId = @sessionId
```

Of course, `@clientDomain` and `@sessionId` are going to be correctly passed in as query parameters in the `QueryMultiple` method, but I'm writing the query in **MySQL Workbench** first, so I've declared the variables there for development.

#### My Problem is:

I can't get it to function in Workbench and I suppose it won't work in Dapper either.

Samples of what I've tried:

[image]

And with `BEGIN`/`END`:

[image]

I've gone through this: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/sql-syntax-compound-statements.html and attempted variations with labels, without labels, etc.

> **Note**: I do not want to write a stored procedure. My desired end result
>   is a .sql file that I'm going to include as an embeded resource in the
>   project, and then load it from code at run time.
>
> I'm using MySQL 5.6, Workbench Community 8.0.15.

What am I missing?

---

#### Solution:

After Jane's comment below, I have two working versions:

```sql
START TRANSACTION;
    SET @clientDomain = 'some-domain';
    SET @sessionId = 'd09a8sd09a7g8gh';

    SELECT *
    FROM sessions.Sessions Sessions
    WHERE Sessions.ClientDomain = @clientDomain AND Sessions.SessionId = @sessionId;

    SELECT *
    FROM sessions.PageVisits PageVisits
    WHERE PageVisits.SessionClientDomain = @clientDomain AND PageVisits.SessionId = @sessionId;
COMMIT;
```

And one with `BEGIN;` but, oddly enough, without `END;` (if I try it, I get an error telling me to look for documentation on how to properly write the `END` statement):

```sql
BEGIN;
    SET @clientDomain = 'some-domain';
    SET @sessionId = 'd09a8sd09a7g8gh';

    SELECT *
    FROM sessions.Sessions Sessions
    WHERE Sessions.ClientDomain = @clientDomain AND Sessions.SessionId = @sessionId;

    SELECT *
    FROM sessions.PageVisits PageVisits
    WHERE PageVisits.SessionClientDomain = @clientDomain AND PageVisits.SessionId = @sessionId;
```

I'm going with the first (`START TRANSACTION`) setting it as `READ ONLY`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are looking for [START TRANSACTION](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/commit.html)

```
START TRANSACTION;

DECLARE @clientDomain VARCHAR(64) SET @clientDomain = 'some-domain';
DECLARE @sessionId VARCHAR(64) SET @sessionId = 'd09a8sd09a7g8gh';

SELECT *
FROM sessions.Sessions Sessions
WHERE Sessions.ClientDomain = @clientDomain AND Sessions.SessionId = @sessionId;

SELECT *
FROM sessions.PageVisits PageVisits
WHERE PageVisits.SessionClientDomain = @clientDomain AND PageVisits.SessionId = @sessionId

COMMIT;
```

Comment: Had to do some minor tweaks but that was really it. I edited my post to include the solution, thanks :)